# How to parse tensor without giving out_type in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, serialization

When parsing a serialized tensor, the `tf.io.parse_tensor` has a required kwarg "out_type". However it seems that tf does not need this to know the type of the serialized tensor because when one gives a wrong type, it manages to print out the good one.

How could then I parse without this arg?

MWE:

```py
tf.io.parse_tensor(tf.io.serialize_tensor(tf.constant([1])), tf.int32)

tf.io.parse_tensor(tf.io.serialize_tensor(tf.constant([1])))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: parse_tensor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'out_type'

tf.io.parse_tensor(tf.io.serialize_tensor(tf.constant([1])), tf.float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/clementwalter/.pyenv/versions/keras_fsl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py", line 2160, in parse_tensor
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/Users/clementwalter/.pyenv/versions/keras_fsl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Type mismatch between parsed tensor (int32) and dtype (float) [Op:ParseTensor]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I worked out a kind of "hacky" solution that can read tensors from different types, casting them to a given type, and works with `@tf.function` (interestingly, it does *not* work without `@tf.function`). The idea is to read the second byte of the `TensorProto` message, which *should* indicate the data type, and then make a `tf.switch_case` to convert from a range of possible source data types. Here is how it could work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Different sets of data types you could use
INTEGER_DTYPES = frozenset({tf.bool, tf.uint8, tf.uint16, tf.uint32, tf.uint64,
                            tf.int8, tf.int16, tf.int32, tf.int64})
FLOAT_DTYPES = frozenset({tf.float16, tf.bfloat16, tf.float32, tf.float64})
COMPLEX_DTYPES = frozenset({tf.complex64, tf.complex128})
REAL_DTYPES = INTEGER_DTYPES | FLOAT_DTYPES
NUMERICAL_DTYPES = REAL_DTYPES | COMPLEX_DTYPES

@tf.function
def parse_tensor_cast(tensor_proto, out_dtype, possible_dtypes=REAL_DTYPES):
    # Prepare branches
    branches = {}
    dtype_idx = [0] * 128
    for i, dtype in enumerate(possible_dtypes):
        dtype_idx[dtype.as_datatype_enum] = i
        branches[i] = lambda: tf.dtypes.cast(
            tf.io.parse_tensor(tensor_proto, dtype), out_dtype)
    dtype_idx = tf.constant(dtype_idx, tf.int32)
    # Extract dtype byte ("hacky" part of the solution)
    dtype_code = tf.strings.substr(tensor_proto, 1, 1)
    dtype_num = tf.io.decode_raw(dtype_code, tf.uint8)[0]
    dtype_num_idx = dtype_idx[tf.dtypes.cast(dtype_num, tf.int32)]
    # Switch operation
    return tf.switch_case(dtype_num_idx, branches)

# Test
serialized_tensors = [
    tf.io.serialize_tensor(tf.constant([1, 2, 3], tf.int32)),
    tf.io.serialize_tensor(tf.constant([1, 2, 3], tf.float64))
]
for t in serialized_tensors:
    tf.print(parse_tensor_cast(t, tf.float32))
# [1 2 3]
# [1 2 3]
```

---

Unfortunately you cannot skip this argument. If there was only eager mode it wouldn't be necessary, but if you want to "graph" this operation (e.g. within a `@tf.function`) then the data type needs to be known in advance, before the actual parsing happens.

If you are only interested in eager mode, then it is not difficult to work around this:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

input_tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], tf.int32)

# A scalar tf.string tensor containing the serialized input_tensor
serialized_tensor = tf.io.serialize_tensor(input_tensor)

# Create a TensorProto from serialized_tensor content
tensor_proto = tf.core.framework.tensor_pb2.TensorProto()
tensor_proto.ParseFromString(serialized_tensor.numpy())

# At this point, this is equivalent to tf.make_tensor_proto
tf.make_tensor_proto(input_tensor)

# Read data back from tensor_proto
tensor_parsed = tf.io.parse_tensor(serialized_tensor.numpy(),
                                   tf.dtypes.as_dtype(tensor_proto.dtype))
tf.debugging.assert_equal(input_tensor, tensor_parsed)

# You can also just directly create the tensor from the extracted message
numpy_parsed = tf.make_ndarray(tensor_proto)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(input_tensor.numpy(), numpy_parsed)
```

Comment: awesome answer thanks. I have juste edited the snippet to hopefully clarify it a bit

Comment: @ClementWalter I added a kind of "trick" solution to the problem that works with `@tf.function`. To be honest, I think the devs could add a similar convenience function to the library in a much better way...